# Is there a way to disable the Translate toolbar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome there's this built-in Google Translate toolbar:

[image]

However, I'm unable to find a way to [disable the darn thing!](http://techcrunch.com/2010/02/14/google-chrome-5-translate-toolbar/)

Has anyone found a way to do so yet? I know it's a dev built, so it will be fixed in the next release. But it would be nice if there was a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's how to do it:](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?hl=en&tid=061eb9ea4b85cdf9)

To disable the translation bar for all sites and languages, go to Tools > Options > Under the Hood > Translate and deselect the box next to "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language I read."

[image]

To disable the translation bar for a particular language or site, click Options on the right side of the bar and select either "Never translate this site" or "Never translate this language."

Answer (score 2):

You're not the only one to complain ... :-)

Apparently, according to a comment on [this page](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/02/07/google-translate-integrated-in-google-chrome-5/):

> Seems like [**Chromium**](http://code.google.com/chromium/) lacks this
>   “feature”. Version is 5.0.321.0, so
>   pretty uptodate and no damn
>   translation-thingy popping up :-)

Comment: Strange I'm running 5.0.322.2...

Comment: Strange that it's STILL not fixed... :-S